# python 2 number comparison is not happening

Tags: python, comparison

Why im not getting accurate result when i compare a with b , where b value is anything between 1 to 9?

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 b=raw_input("Enter value of b:\n")
 a = 10
 if a>b:
  print("a is larger")
 else:
  print("b is larger")
```

Comment: note that if a == b it will still print "b is larger"

Comment: Because `b` is a string, not a number.

Comment: Did you even try to see what is in `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 3):

The `raw_input` command returns a string. You should cast 'b' as an integer before the comparison.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
b=raw_input("Enter value of b:\n")
b=int(b)
a = 10
if a>b:
   print("a is larger")
else:
   print("b is larger")
```

Comment: b=int(raw_input("Enter value of b:\n")) this fixed the issue thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is because raw_input takes the input as a string . what you need is

b= input("Enter value of b:\n")

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string with integer. You need to cast `raw_input` with `int`.

```
a = 10
b = raw_input('Enter value of b:')
if (b.isdigit()):
    b = int(b)
    if a>b:
        print("a is larger")
    else:
        print("b is larger")
else:
    print("b is not a number that can be compared with a")
```

Python Documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

> raw_input([prompt])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

`NOTE`: You would need to add better error-handling as in your code user can enter a non-numeric number and it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are comparing `string` with `integer` as `raw_input` in `python2.x` and `input()` in `python3.x` always returns `string`. So you have to typecast it to `int` before comparing with `int` type:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
b=int(raw_input("Enter value of b:\n"))
a = 10
if a>b:
    print("a is larger")
else:
    print("b is larger")
```